# SQL Count Function - Need some help

Tags: sql, count

Looking for some help in making an SQL query where:

If the value per hour is more than 40 then it will count it and this count will display how many times in that hour the value was above 40.

I am very new to SQL so please forgive my n00bness :)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about your table?

Comment: Can you post the table structure and specify which database you are using?  (mysql, mssql, postgres...)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Count(*) As myCount FROM myTable WHERE colPerHour > 40
```

This will return one row with a column called myCount. The value in that cell will be your desired number.

Comment: Thanks! but does this go in the table and count how many times in 1 hour the value was greater than 40?

Comment: if there is a specific time range you are looking for, add this to the end: AND colTimeStamp BETWEEN '[time range start]' AND '[time range end]'   ....replacing the text in brackets with your start and ending timestamps to apply the correct filter.

Comment: @Adam: You should really add some example to your question (both source data and expected output). Then it would be much easier to see what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

```
select colperhour, count (*)
from mytable
where colperhour > 40
group by colperhour
```

This should give you each value of colperhour greater than 40 (which are in the table), along with the number of times each value exists